# What is the operator $\bigoplus$ in the context of function spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking at the statement, 'define a global function space $V_h \equiv \bigoplus_{k=1}^{K} V_h^k$, s.t. $V_h^k \equiv \textrm{span}\{\phi_j^k\}_{j=1,2...N_p}$  where $\phi_j^k$ are polynomial basis functions of order $j$ on an element $k$.

I get that $V_h^k$ is the set of all functions that can be represented by polynomials up to order $N_p$; but what is $V_h$?

Comment: [Direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that means?  Perhaps in an 'answer' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\bigoplus$ represents a [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum); $U\oplus V:=\{u+v:u\in U,v\in V\}$.

So, in your context, $V_h :=\bigoplus_{k=1}^{K} V_h^k=\{v_h^1+v_h^2+\cdots+v_h^K:v_h^i\in V_h^i\}$.